# How to send dictionary values to a function

Tags: python

I have a Python dictionary assigned to a variable.

```
mpm_holidays = {
    "New Year's Day (Observed)": (None, True),
    "Martin Luther King Jr. Day": ("art/MLKDay.png", True),
    "2022-02-14": ("art/ValentinesDay.png", False),
    "Good Friday": ("art/GoodFriday.png", True),
    "2022-04-16": ("art/GoodFriday.png", True),
    "Memorial Day": ("art/MemorialDay.png", True),
    "2022-05-28": (None, True),
    "2022-06-19": ("art/Juneteenth.png", False),
    "Independence Day": ("art/IndependenceDay.png", True),
    "Independence Day (Observed)": (None, True),
    "Labor Day": ("art/LaborDay.png", True),
    "2022-09-03": (None, True),
    "2022-09-05": (None, True),
    "Veterans Day": ("art/VeteransDay.png", True),
    "Veterans Day (Observed)": (None, True),
    "2022-10-31": ("art/Halloween.png", False),
    "Thanksgiving": ("art/Thanksgiving.png", True),
    "Day After Thanksgiving": (None, True),
    "Christmas Eve": ("art/ChristmasEve.png", True),
    "Christmas Eve (Observed)": (None, True),
    "Christmas Day": ("art/ChristmasDay.png", True),
    "New Year's Eve": ("art/NewYearsEve.png", True)
}
```

I want to feed this variable's values through a function I have:

```
def overlays(art_to_use_, closure_):
    """ Imprint closure and/or holiday artwork. """
    if art_to_use_:
        calendarSheet.paste(
            Image.open(art_to_use_).convert("RGBA"),
            (0, 0),
            mask=Image.open(art_to_use_).convert("RGBA")
        )
    if closure_:
        calendarSheet.paste(
            Image.open(STATUS_CLOSED).convert("RGBA"),
            (0, 0),
            mask=Image.open(STATUS_CLOSED).convert("RGBA")
        )
    calendarSheet.save(calendarSheetFilename, format="png")
```

What am I missing? How would I write this out?

I know that I'm not grasping something about how to map the values to the requisite parameters of the function.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do the values of the dictionary correspond to `(art_to_use_, closure_)`?

If so, you could do 

`for art_to_use, closure in mpm_holidays.values():
    overlays(art_to_use, closure)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop over `mpm_holidays.values()` to get all the values.

```
for art, closed in mpm_holidays.values():
    overlays(art, closed)
```

Comment: Is the L at the end of the for statement a typo?

Comment: Yes! It's a typo

Comment: This is very illustrative and helpful. Thank you.

Comment: This is an adjacent question: Is there a way to do this that somehow matches only particular key-value pairs as it loops? I'm trying to use a dictionary to hold a list of holidays, but not loop through them all at once every time I go to pull a match from the dictionary.

Comment: If you just want a particular key, you don't need  a loop. Just use `mpm_holidays[key]`